# access device width in the nextjs middleware

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In my `nextjs` app router project I have a `categories` page that I wanna show this page in the screen width size below 1024px and else redirect to the landing page `/`. I wanna use middleware to handle this scenario. but I can't use the media query hook in the middleware. how can I access device user width to manage that?

my middleware

```
import {
  NextResponse,
  type NextFetchEvent,
  type NextRequest,
} from "next/server";

import { CustomMiddleware } from "./chain";

export function manageCategoriesMiddleware(middleware: CustomMiddleware) {
  return async (request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) => {
    const response = NextResponse.next();

    // show categories only in screen width size below 1024 else redirect to the landing page
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname === "/categories") {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    }

    // Call the next middleware and pass the request and response
    return middleware(request, event, response);
  };
}
```